# CSS translate animation stutter/jank

Tags: css, css-animations

This trivial CSS animation code snippet doesn't get 60 fps in Chrome 58 on a MacBook Pro (15-inch, 2016), according to the Performance tab in Dev Tools. It's *mostly* smooth, but the square occasionally visibly skips a frame or two during animation. Why? How do I fix this?

EDIT: It still reproduces in Chrome 79 on a 16-inch 2019 MacBook Pro.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 10vh;
  width: 10vh;
  margin: 10vh;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { transform: translateX(1000%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I don't know if this'll make a difference but change dimensions to this: `height: 10vh;  width: 10vw;  margin: 10vh 10vw;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to get a Chromium engineer to look into this on Twitter.

https://mobile.twitter.com/flackrw/status/1225116562010656769

> Sadly the animation isn't composited because the percentage transform keyframe is dependent on a layout size. This isn't fundamental and it's on our short list of things to fix! https://crbug.com/389359 It's a good example of why compositing effects helps a lot.

But switching from `translateX(1000%)` to `400px` didn't help. https://css-stutter.glitch.me/ So another bug was filed:

https://mobile.twitter.com/flackrw/status/1225144162858799104

> Thanks for trying - I'm able to see the same! I filed https://crbug.com/1049248 and recorded a trace where I saw that the call to SwapBuffers is taking a long time once in a while. Feel free to add any details I may have missed.

So hopefully we'll have an answer there soon-ish. I also see the same issue on Safari 13 for macOS 10.15, so I've filed a WebKit bug as well.

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=207282

There appears to be no way to work around this issue at this time.

Answer (score 0):

I'd don't see a lot of issues in Chrome on a 2017 MBP 13" using your code. However, replacing the vh/wv units with `px` to avoid any browser overhead from checking dynamic sizes and adding `will-change: transform;` cleaned it up the minimal issues I was seeing.

There's some pretty good information in this article [Smooth as Butter: Achieving 60 FPS Animations with CSS3](https://medium.com/outsystems-experts/how-to-achieve-60-fps-animations-with-css3-db7b98610108) that might give you additional ideas.

However, at this point, I might attribute any jankiness to other elements on the page that aren't in your example.

```css
div {
  background-color: red;
  height: 20px;
  width: 20px;
  margin: 20px;
  animation-name: slide;
  animation-duration: 5s;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  will-change: transform;
}

@keyframes slide {
  0% { transform: translateX(0); }
  50% { transform: translateX(1000%); }
  100% { transform: translateX(0); }
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```

Comment: I think you just got lucky. If you view it in Chrome Dev Tools, you can see it's still dropping frames. I managed to work with a Chromium engineer to repro the bug; it's now filed as https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1049248